# Modelling DC/DC-Converter

Tags: pwm, buck, boost, buck-boost, state-space

i want to model a cascaded Buck/Boost-Converter with FAST like mentioned here: https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202013.pdf.

The goal is to implement a controller, to verify constant Voltage at the Output: 
\begin{align}
V_{out}=355V.
\end{align} 
The Power will be: 
\begin{align}
P = 3.6kW,
\end{align}
so the Resistance at the Output is:
\begin{align}
R_L = 35 \Omega.
\end{align}

The Topology looks like this: 
[image: Topology]

My Question is how to model the the Converter in consideration to the Output-Voltage and the Resistance?

I would think I should model my known Values for the Output-Voltage like this:

[image: Topology-2]

or is it easier to model only the Converter Dynamics without these parameters?

edit: another Question is, if i can make an order reduction in case of the Voltage over C1 is equivalent to Uin?

Comment: This circuit just acts as a buck (Sbuck switching and Sboost always low) when Vin > Vout and acts as a boost (Sbuck always low and Sboost switching) when Vin < Vout. You probably just need to do separate analyses for the two cases.

Comment: yes, i know. The Question is, if I want to calculate the Small-Signal Transfer-Function, do i ignore RL and Vout (which values i know), or do I model them to, so that they impact is also in the Tfunction? (Vout and RL are important values for the equilibrium point (which is the point of action of the Tfunction), so i think they should be in there, as far as i know)

Comment: 400 volts across 35 ohms is 4.6 kW not 3.6 kW.

Comment: yes, sure. I have corrected it. Vout is 355V

Comment: If you model a load resistance in series with a voltage source, then \$R_L\$ isn't \$35 \Omega\$.  I would be tempted to model it with a current source on the output, and then disturb the current source (with a step, like from 9.5A to 10.2A) so that I could estimate the output impedance -- but note that the output impedance will be strongly affected by the control rule you apply.

Comment: okay, so maybe the best way to go is ignoring the Output and just analyse and calculate the TFunction Vout/d, Vout/Vin without RL and Vout?